# Need help installing matcaffe on ubuntu

Tags: matlab, caffe

I don't know if this is the correct to ask this but I am trying to use caffe on matlab to run some research project. So far I have succesfully do make matcaffe but I encountered error during make mattest. These are the code that I got from it.

```
                             < M A T L A B (R) >
                  Copyright 1984-2015 The MathWorks, Inc.
                   R2015a (8.5.0.197613) 64-bit (glnxa64)
                             February 12, 2015


To get started, type one of these: helpwin, helpdesk, or demo.
For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.


    Academic License

Invalid MEX-file '/home/cgal/caffe/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64':
/usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: symbol TIFFReadRGBATileExt version LIBTIFF_4.0 not
defined in file libtiff.so.5 with link time reference

Error in caffe.set_mode_cpu (line 5)
caffe_('set_mode_cpu');

Error in caffe.run_tests (line 6)
caffe.set_mode_cpu();
```

I am running this project on ubuntu 18.04 with matlab R2015a since I read that caffe is only compatible with this version of matlab. Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  May I suggest to expand your answer by clarifying how to use this export and why you think it will solve the problem.  this will help to use your answer and, eventually hlp to find similar answers.